# MongoDB использование памяти

Tags: mongodb, администрирование

Используем монго для логирования действий пользователей в сапр программе. Пользователей больше ста человек, база стремительно растет. 
Можно ли ограничить использование оперативной памяти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При относительно больших размерах вашей БД и индексов, MongoDB будет использовать всю доступную память для кэшей, [журналов](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/), и т.д.

Также, потребление памяти зависит и от выбранного хранилища данных. Почитайте секции Memory Use для [**MMAPv1**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/mmapv1/#mmapv1-ram) и для [**WiredTiger**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/wiredtiger/#wiredtiger-ram).

Вкратце — большей частью памяти, занимаемой МонгоДБ, на самом деле всё равно управляет операционная система. И если какому-то другому приложению понадобится больше памяти, MongoDB её освободит.

Для WiredTiger есть опция [**storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB), позволяющая ограничить кэш WiredTiger. Но кэш — далеко не всё, чем MongoDB занимает память, поэтому при изменении этой опции не рассчитывайте на предсказуемые результаты.

**Вывод:** вручную ограничить занимаемую MongoDB память у вас не получится. Но этого делать и не нужно, потому что память освободится автоматически, если она будет нужна ОС или другим программам.